# How to change background image with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I'm having problem changing the background-img of a div using jquery:

Initially I set it as so

```
#div-id {
background: url(../images/conv1.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Then in a script that starts later after a timeout I do this:

```
$('#div-id').css('background', 'url("../images/conv2.png")');
```

When I do this however the image just disappears, yet when I look at element inspector in Chrome-tool its says:

```
$('#div-id').css('background', 'url("../images/conv3.png")');
```

I am lost as to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `background-image` as a property both in the CSS and in jQuery, and apply the other properties in CSS seperately (background--position, background-size, background-repeat etc.)

```
#div-id {
  background-image: url(../images/conv1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

and

```
$('#div-id').css('background-image', 'url(../images/conv2.png)');
```

Comment: This hasn't seemed to work..Chrome-tools shows element.style with the new image name, and has it crossed out in the div part. The image is also accessible

Comment: I added an example. BTW: No quotes are necessary for the URL

Comment: Thanks I think it was an issue with the location of the files..its because my JS was stored in a different folder and so the ../ was not going to the correct folder...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add each attribute individually:

```
$("#RenderedText").css('background-image', 'url(' + imageString + ')');  
$("#RenderedText").css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');  
$("#RenderedText").css('background-position', 'right top');
```